# Reading of hex file in testbench : Verilog

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I have converted an image file into hex file which has R,G,B and alpha values in multiple columns. For example :

```
3c 48 36 ff 1d 2b 19 ff 08 18 06 ff 08 17 05 ff
14 1f 0d ff 1b 22 11 ff 1a 1f 0e ff 1a 1b 0b ff
1d 1a 0b ff 20 1a 0b ff 23 1a 0c ff 23 1c 0d ff
24 1d 0e ff 24 1d 0e ff 21 1c 0d ff 23 1c 0d ff
1f 1a 0b ff 1e 19 0a ff 1c 19 0a ff 1e 1a 0b ff
20 1a 0b ff 24 18 0b ff 23 18 0a ff 21 18 0a ff
```

Now I want a way to read and store this data as a collection of 32 bits( i.e. 4bytes). If I do not know how bytes are present in the file (since file can be of any size), how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file in that given format, you can use the `$readmemh` system call to take those values and put them in a Verilog array:

```
localparam MAX_SIZE 1024 /* Set this to the maxium image size in bytes */

reg [7:0] image_8[MAX_SIZE-1:0];
reg [31:0] image_32[(MAX_SIZE/4)-1:0];
integer i;

initial begin
  $readmemh("file.hex", image);
  for (i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE/4; i = i + 1) begin
    image_32[i] = ({24'b0, image_8[i*4]} << 24) | ({24'b0, image_8[i*4 + 1]} << 16) | ({24'b0, image_8[i*4 + 2]} << 8) | (image_8[i*4 + 3]);
  end
end
```

That should get you your image as a Verilog array, with each element being 32-bits long.

(Note that smaller files will leave a bunch of `'x` values in the array, so you can check for this to determine length if needed)

Comment: Is there any way that I can avoid those "x" values for smaller files? Because I have to convert the output data into image again. So too many "x" values may not give me the required image.

Comment: If you need to create an output hex file, you can use `$writememh` and include the starting and ending addresses, where the ending address isnt the max size, but the true size; like `$writememh("out.hex", image_32, 0, image_size - 1);`. You can also always define the size as the parameter instead of a maximum size, but youll need to recompile for each new image if you do that.

Comment: Hi, Can $fread be used to read hex files? or is it only for reading binary data?

Comment: @saigeethaseri You can certainly use `$fread` to read hex files, but you'd have to do all the parsing work yourself from the binary data read in. Hex files for `$readmemh` take the form of human readable text to represent the values while `$fread` is for reading in raw binary files; so pick which one based on what your file looks like (ie, if you can read the data in a text editor, dont use `$fread`)